# Edge сбрасывает css страницы

Tags: javascript, css, microsoft-edge

На сайте http://www.klerk.ru/ в браузере Edge периодически при загрузке, точнее уже в процессе рендера страницы внезапно сбрасываются стили. Ошибка появляется на разных страницах, при повторной загрузке - пропадает. Чаще всего возникает при первом заходе на какую-либо из страниц, например при такой последовательности:
 Главная - Новости (фейлит) - ctrR (все ок) - Главная - Новости (фейлит). В общем-то больше ничего более внятного про ошибку сказать не получается: в консоли и отладчике неочевидно что именно вызывает такой эффект. В других браузерах ничего похожего не происходит. Может кто-то сталкивался, боролся с такими багами? Или догадывается в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите в консоли в каком виде приходят css-файлы (и вообще, есть ли какие ошибки связанные со стилями). Возможно имеет место ошибка в настройках сервера, когда css-файлы передаются как `plain/text`.

Сталкивался с подобным багом, правда он присутствовал во всех браузерах. Ошибка была в неверных заголовках (точнее выводилось 2 типа заголовков, решил убрав один из заголовков с `plain/text`). Попробуйте перенести сайт на другой сервер, посмотрите как будет работать (конечно, при условии, что сайт ваш).

Еще одна из возможных причин, это то, что Edge неверно читает такие ссылки:

```
//www.klerk.ru/html2016/styles/style_tools.css?v5
```

Попробуйте использовать относительные пути.